# Looking for an Implementation of Blake-512 Hashing Algorithm in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hash

Is anyone aware of or has an example of an open implementation of the [Blake-512 hashing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_%28hash_function%29) written and optimized for JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a JS implementation of this algorithm.  The source code is available here: [blake512.js](http://blog.scottlogic.com/archive/2012/02/blake512.js).

The only global function is called "blake512" and takes 3 parameters.. the message to hash (which it treats as a UCS-2 encoded binary string), a optional 16 character salt (encoded in the same way as the message) and a boolean to say if you want the output in hex characters or just as a binary sequence encoded in the same manner as the message.

e.g.

```
blake512("\u0000", null, true);
```

returns the encoding of the binary sequence: 0000000000000000, using the salt 000...000 in hex, which is: 0CD686174DC1451DCF2E54BCD55B868BF84F54E4F6454AFD599ABD0F3361FB85F09DDA2C7C6CB9A97FA6DCA2ED8068C8E8A69B66C4F8BD819CBFD5A0BD9D8E7C.

There is a blog post which outlines how the implementation works here: http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/29/blake-512-in-javascript.html.

Comment: @Mark, Dude why do you make it alert? There's no way to CtrlC text in an alert box..

Comment: If you're looking for the code that makes that little panel in the demo work its: http://blog.scottlogic.com/archive/2012/02/testBlakeHash.js I guess you can just change it to do what you want.